# Sorting a list of ten numbers with selection sort in assembly language

Tags: sorting, assembly, x86

sorting a list of ten numbers with selection sort in assembly language.
How does i convert this bubble sort method into  selection sort method

```
`[org 0x0100]
jmp start
data: dw 60, 55, 45, 50, 40, 35, 25, 30, 10, 0
swap: db 0
start: mov bx, 0 ; initialize array index to zero
mov byte [swap], 0 ; rest swap flag to no swaps
loop1: mov ax, [data+bx] ; load number in ax
cmp ax, [data+bx+2] ; compare with next number
jbe noswap ; no swap if already in order
mov dx, [data+bx+2] ; load second element in dx
mov [data+bx+2], ax ; store first number in second
mov [data+bx], dx ; store second number in first
mov byte [swap], 1 ; flag that a swap has been done
noswap: add bx, 2 ; advance bx to next index
cmp bx, 18 ; are we at last index
jne loop1 ; if not compare next two
cmp byte [swap], 1 ; check if a swap has been done
je start ; if yes make another pass
mov ax, 0x4c00 ;  terminate program
int 0x21`
```

Comment: when you ask a question here you really want to show what research you have done so far and what you have tried. See the StackOverflow guide on how to ask good questions: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Also, I'm assuming this is homework. For that, you should really consider asking it as such, ensuring that you aren't asking people to do your homework for you. See this Meta post: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions

Answer (score 0):

The key here is to change your loop. Currently it's swapping adjacent numbers. You need to change it to copy the rightmost element into a register, and shift the pre-existing sorted array to the right until the element you just shifted is greater than or equal to the previously rightmost element you just copied into your register.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will be helpfull. I wrote this a long time ago. Realmode intel assembler.

MAIN.ASM

```
SSTACK SEGMENT PARA STACK 'STACK'
    DW 128 DUP(?)
SSTACK ENDS


DSEG SEGMENT PUBLIC 'DATA'

    S LABEL BYTE
    ARR DB 'IHGFED27182392JASKD1O12312345CBA'
    LEN EQU ($-S)

    PUBLIC TMP
    PUBLIC MIN
    TMP DW ?
    MIN DW ?

DSEG ENDS

CSEG SEGMENT 'CODE'
    ASSUME CS:CSEG, SS:SSTACK, DS:DSEG

        EXTRN OUTPUT:NEAR
        EXTRN SORT:NEAR

START:      MOV AX, DSEG
        MOV DS, AX

        MOV BX, OFFSET ARR
        MOV CX, LEN
        CALL OUTPUT


        MOV AX, 60

        CMP AX, 0
        JZ NO_SORT
        CMP AX, 1
        JZ NO_SORT

        MOV BX, OFFSET ARR
        MOV CX, LEN
        CALL SORT


NO_SORT:    MOV BX, OFFSET ARR
        MOV CX, LEN
        CALL OUTPUT

        MOV AH, 4CH
        MOV AL, 0
        INT 21H







CSEG ENDS
     END START
```

SORT.ASM

```
DSEG SEGMENT PUBLIC 'DATA'

    EXTRN TMP:WORD
    EXTRN MIN:WORD

DSEG ENDS


CSEG SEGMENT 'CODE'
    ASSUME CS:CSEG, DS:DSEG

    PUBLIC SORT


SORT PROC;              (AX - N, BX - ARRAY ADDRESS, CX - ARRAY LENGTH)

        PUSH SI
        PUSH DI
        PUSH DX

        CALL COMPARE_MIN

        DEC CX
        MOV AX, CX

        XOR SI, SI
        XOR DI, DI


 L1:    
        PUSH CX
        MOV MIN, SI

        MOV TMP, DI
        INC DI

        MOV CX, AX


        L2:

        MOV DH, BYTE PTR[BX+DI]

        PUSH SI
        MOV SI, MIN
        MOV DL, BYTE PTR[BX+SI]
        POP SI

        CMP DH, DL
        JA OLD_MIN


NEW_MIN:    MOV MIN, DI


OLD_MIN:    INC DI
            DEC CX

        CMP CX, TMP
        JNZ L2

SWAP:       PUSH DI
        MOV DI, MIN

        MOV DL, BYTE PTR[BX+DI]
        MOV DH, BYTE PTR[BX+SI]

        MOV BYTE PTR [BX+SI], DL
        MOV BYTE PTR [BX+DI], DH

        POP DI

        INC SI
        MOV DI, SI

   POP CX
   LOOP L1

    POP DX
    POP DI
    POP DI


    RET


SORT ENDP





COMPARE_MIN PROC;   (AX - A, CX - B     CX - MIN)   

        PUSH AX

        CMP AX, CX
        JB B__A
        JA A__B

A__B:       MOV CX, CX
        JMP EX

B__A:       MOV CX, AX
        JMP EX

EX:     POP AX
        RET

COMPARE_MIN ENDP






CSEG ENDS

     END
```

OUTPUT.ASM

```
CSEG SEGMENT 'CODE'
    ASSUME CS:CSEG

    PUBLIC OUTPUT

OUTPUT PROC ; (BX - ARRAY ADDRESS, CX - ARRAY LENGTH)

    PUSH DX
    PUSH SI
    PUSH AX

    XOR SI, SI

    MOV AH, 02H

OUTARR: MOV DL,[BX+SI]
    INT 21H

    INC SI

        LOOP OUTARR

    MOV DL, 10
    INT 21H 

    POP AX
    POP SI
    POP DX

    RET

OUTPUT ENDP
CSEG ENDS
     END
```